# Saving to excel file causes error in c# windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, excel, console

Here is the code:

```
try
{
    if (File.Exists("c:\\Reports\\" + fileName))
    {
        File.Delete("c:\\Reports\\" + fileName);
    }
    _book.SaveAs("c:\\Reports\\" + fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                   null, null, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared,
                   false, false, null, null, null);
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    throw ee;
}
```

On saving to excel format . I have got the following error as follows..

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I am using MS Office version 2000.

Dll using is Interop.excel 1.4.0.0

Using Visual studio 2008 + c# console application

Comment: You are checking if `C:\Reports\fileName` exists, then trying to delete `C:\fileName`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Better re-count your `null`, `null` sequences.

Comment: Have you tried setting the ConflictResolution parameter to xlLocalSessionChanges?

Comment: MSDN [Workbook.SaveAs Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

use _book.SaveCopyAs("c:\Reports\" + fileName)